# Java: missing variable as dice and value

Tags: java

Three dice objects and toss each one. The results of the toss should be displayed in an output window. I'm working on this exercise. I've two classes: **App** and **Dice** classes to work with, that's it.

I'm not sure how to make it work in class App. Correct me if I've mistaken on Class App as below.

**UPDATED:**

There is an error on class App that read no variable and I've used "Dice" as Dice [ 1 ] incorrectly and it should read as *face.Value* instead. **Using the accepted answer as below" **Dice: "+ faceValue.** as a solution for code of the following:
//UPDATED CODE and CORRECTED
oBox.println( "You threw : " + diceOne.getFaceValue() + " " + diceTwo.getFaceValue() + " " + diceThree.getFaceValue() );**

**class App as below**

```
import javabook.*;

class App
{

public static void main(String args[])
{
    App thisProgram = new App();
    //Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

}   
    //outside a main class
    public App()
    {

        //contsructor
        //Dice aDice

        //set variables
        //int anDice = 0;
        //int faceValue;

        //Declare objects
        Dice diceOne;       
        Dice diceTwo;       
        Dice diceThree;

        int aNumber = 0;
        //int afaceValue;

        //declare objects
        MainWindow mWindow;
        Dice aDice;     
        InputBox iBox;
        OutputBox oBox;


        //create objects                
        mWindow = new MainWindow();     //swap the words around e.g. MainWindow mWindow; to mWindow = new MainWindow();
        aDice = new Dice();             //aTriangle = new Triangle();
        iBox = new InputBox(mWindow);   //mWindow is a white screen behind the Input Box
        oBox = new OutputBox(mWindow);  //mWindow is a white screen behind the Input Box

        diceOne     = new Dice();
    diceTwo     = new Dice();
    diceThree   = new Dice();

        //Use objects
        mWindow.show();
        oBox.show();

        //LOOP
        do
        {
            //Get Input
            aNumber = iBox.getInteger("Enter 1 to throw the dice, or 0 to exit: ");
            //Process
            diceOne.throwDice();
            diceTwo.throwDice();
            diceThree.throwDice();
            //Output
                    //UPDATED and CORRECTED
            oBox.println( "You threw : " + diceOne.getFaceValue() + " " + diceTwo.getFaceValue() + " " + diceThree.getFaceValue() );
        }
        while (aNumber > 0 );


        //get input of base and height
        //aDice = iBox.getDouble("Please enter the base of a triangle: ");

        //Get Input
        //aNumber = iBox.getInteger("Enter 1 to throw the dice, or 0 to exit: ");

        System.exit(0);
        //end.

    }
```

**class Dice as below**

```
class Dice
{
    //public static void main(String args[])

    //data
    //private constants
    final int NUMBER_OF_SIDES = 6;

    //private variables
    private int faceValue;

    //constructors
    public Dice()
    {
        this.faceValue = 0;     //zero if not thrown.
    }

    //methods - behavious
    public void throwDice()
    {
        this.faceValue = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * NUMBER_OF_SIDES);
    }

    //method - get (accessors) and sets (mutators)
    public int getFaceValue()
    {
        return(this.faceValue);
        //System.out.println ("Dice: "+ .faceValue()); 
    }   
}
```

**Compiler result as below**
[image: This is a result] Not sure if I'm entering as three dice objects and toss each one? but it doesn't look like toss each one?

![enter image description here][2]

Comment: main is not a class , it's a method. Where is the problem? Have you tested your code?

Comment: A println after a return instruction, declarations of diceOne, diceTwo and diceThree commented. Are you sure your code compiles?

Comment: I couldn't make three dice and toss one in Class App that will work. I think Dice class is ok.

Comment: I've tried both, the issue I've is Dice aDice; and aDice = new Dice(); belong toegther. But three dice Dice diceOne; Dice diceTwo; and Dice diceThree; are causing problems.

Comment: What exactly do you mean "causing problems"? Is an exception thrown? Doesn't it compile? ...

Comment: I've posted a compiler result as above.

Comment: When you use `diceOne` etc. You have to declare it first. That means you always have to have pairs of `Dice diceX;` and `diceX = new Dice();` or `Dice diceX = new Dice();` then you can use the instance. Note that the variable has to be visible, where you want to use it. For example a variable declared inside a for-loop will not be visible after the closing "}"

Comment: I repeat: lines that declare the dices are commented. It cannot compile.

Comment: Ok, it is Dice: Dice diceOne; Dice diceTwo; Dice diceThree; But I've Dice aDice; as well? What is the best way to call three dices without clashing the declarations of Dice aDice;?

Comment: Why do think they clash?

Comment: I'm not sure that is why I'm asking here.

Comment: Quit copying something you found on the internet (or in a book example) and think it out for yourself.  And if you don't understand it, study.  If there is a particular point you can't "get" in your studies, come back here to ask a specific question.

Comment: They don't clash :) You can instantiate as many instances of a Class as you like (and memory allows you). The variables all just need to have different names, which is the case in above code.

Comment: @Hot Licks. Somebody else is asking me a question and please there is no need to harsh. It wasn't book example that I was copying, it is my previous working example that worked. Java is not easy and this is how I learn by asking questions. I'm sure you were like me when you first started? Be gentle.

Comment: @Fildor. Thanks, I'll try this and see how it is complie.

Comment: @Fildor. Can I use DiceOne diceOne; DiceTwo diceOne; DiceThree diceOne; as part of declaration.

Comment: No. You want three instances of the *same* class. So it has to be `Dice diceOne; Dice diceTwo; ... `.

Comment: I've updated class App as above.

Comment: You still have to uncomment the three declarations of the instance variables where it sais "//Declare objects" :)

Comment: 1 error.  symbol  : variable Dice location: class Dice. System.out.println ("Dice: "+ Dice[1].faceValue()); //getFaceValue //add in new Dice from Dice

Comment: `Dice` isn't a variable, it's a class.

Comment: There is no variable "Dice". Dice[1] would be the 2nd item in an *Array* that is accessed via a variable called "Dice". Just make it `"Dice: "+ faceValue`

Comment: I've changed //create objects that reads diceOne = new DiceOne(); diceOne = new DiceTwo(); and diceOne = new DiceThree(); is that acceptable?

Comment: Can you just update the code in your question? If that means that you commented out that stuff, it's ok.

Comment: I've comment out //System.out.println ("Dice: "+ .faceValue()); and see the update as above.

Comment: Congratulations :) But really : work on your understanding of Classes and Objects. Good luck to you.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying very hard even I got -4 from peers not bad could have been worse ;-). The only way is practice and practice with plenty of mistakes. Is there a way that I can accept your answer with a green tick?

Comment: Now I'll need work on to "toss each one" to be displayed in an output window. Its clear that I've to do that on Class App after //Loop

Comment: BTW, "dice" is plural.  The singular is "die".  As in ["Alea iacta est"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alea_iacta_est).

Comment: @Hot Licks. That is interesting, I never knew that. I though it was typo error or choice of a word? How does that work in Dice / Die for java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no variable "Dice". Dice[1] would be the 2nd item in an Array that is accessed via a variable called "Dice". Just make it "Dice: "+ faceValue

Comment: Cheers. Now I'll need work on to "toss each one" to be displayed in an output window. Its clear that I've to do that on Class App after //Loop

Comment: OK, try what you can do. I'm pretty sure you'll be able to work that out. It's practically copy & paste.

Comment: I guess it is something like this: oBox.println( "You threw : " + diceOne.getFaceValue() ); and then oBox.println( "You threw : " + diceTwo.getFaceValue() ); and then oBox.println( "You threw : " + diceThree.getFaceValue() );